# Android Animation ImageView

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I have 4 ImageViews which need to be moving from right to left. This is the sample video of my animation: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-Jk0rK9-8gUQTlUb3BrVGZEUHc/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the code I'm working on:

```
   private void getCorrectObject() {

    List<Integer> objects = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int arr : images){
        objects.add(arr);
    }

    // Shuffle the collection
    Collections.shuffle(objects);

    iv.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.txtStage4_object1));
    iv.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.txtStage4_object2));
    iv.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.txtStage4_object3));
    iv.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.txtStage4_object4));

    Collections.shuffle(iv);

    iv.get(0).setImageResource(images[0]); // Correct Image
    iv.get(1).setImageResource(images[1]); 
    iv.get(2).setImageResource(images[2]); 
    iv.get(3).setImageResource(images[3]); 

    Animation accelerate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.accelerate_2);
    //accelerate.setRepeatCount(-1);
    //accelerate.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

    iv.get(0).startAnimation(accelerate);
    iv.get(1).startAnimation(accelerate);
    iv.get(2).startAnimation(accelerate);
    iv.get(3).startAnimation(accelerate);

    for (int i = 0; i < tagList.length; i++) { 
        iv.get(i).setTag(tagList[i]); 
        iv.get(i).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener()); 

    } 



}
```

XML:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<translate
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

But it's not doing as what I expected. Any ideas? I'd truly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: What's the result you get, currently? And judging by the video, I would do it with canvas. (pirate objects? arr!)

Comment: @DanielMonteiro I had it moving from right to left, but it just stays on the screen, it isn't disappearing to the left side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a little bit on what the container layout is for each `ImageView`, but your problem is most likely this; you need to make a couple modifications to the start point on the animation.

Using `-100%` says start at an x-position that is off to the left at a distance of my (ImageView) width and move to the right (to `0%`, or the current laid out position).

Since you mentioned moving right to left, we probably first want to drop the minus sign and do `100%` -> `0%`, which is a right to left movement.

You also probably want to make this position relative to the parent view (which is likely matched to the width of the screen), i.e. `100%p`, which will start at an offset beyond the parent views bound.

So all you may need to do is modify your animation XML like so:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but how can I make it disappear on the screen and reappear again?

Comment: You may have to provide more information about your layout if this is not working for you, because this animation should start the views off-screen (unless the parent view of the `ImageView`s does not fill the screen width) and move them back on-screen to their original position.